# How to extract text from the webpage?

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel

I have an excel sheet with a column filled with Patent numbers. I need to extract the title of each corresponding patent and place it to the cell next to the patent number. So, the code should perform the following:

1. Visit espacenet.com and open up the patent number for which the title is required.
2. Fetch the title.
3. Place it in the excel sheet in the desired cell.

Here's the code which works perfectly for the 1st patent number but gives an error immediately after that. The error says: 
"
Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':

Automation error
The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.
"

The code:

```
Sub tryextraction()

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim num1 As Integer
Dim num0 As Integer
Dim sdd As String
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
num1 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
'ie.Visible = True
For num0 = 2 To num1
ie.navigate "http://worldwide.espacenet.com/searchResults?compact=false&PN=" & Range("A" & num0).Value & "&ST=advanced&locale=en_EP&DB=EPODOC"
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set doc = ie.document
sdd = Trim(doc.getElementsByTagName("a")(88).innerText)
ie.Quit
Range("B" & num0).Value = sdd
Next num0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `ie.Quit` line out of your `For... Next` loop and to the end. Otherwise its closing IE after the first instance.